# Setup static route from main router to sub router

Tags: networking, router, routing, static-routes

I have two routers say Router1 and Router2. My Router1(DHCP:192.168.0.1) is connected to my ISP and has a few devices connected to it. Router2(DHCP:192.168.1.1) is connected to the ethernet port on Router1 with IP address 192.168.0.5 with respect to Router1.
[image]
I have a DNS server connected to Router2 with an IP address let's say 192.168.1.12. I want to create a static route such that Router1(and its connected devices) can access the DNS server connected to Router2. And my configuration looks like the below image but I cannot get it to work(ping from Router1 connected device fails with **Request timeout for icmp_seq**).
[image]

PS:

- Due to few other things running along with the DNS server I cannot move that device to Router1.
- All devices listed here are set to static IP addresses

Comment: Turning off DHCP & NAT on router2 is usually the best way to solve that, is that possible? That way Router1 controls everything, everyone can talk, router2 is just a switch

Comment: Devices connected to Router1 are DHCP and/or have Router1 as their DNS & GW? If so they SHOULD be asking it how to get to 192.168.1.12 which it then redirects to Router2 IP 192.168.0.5 so you've done that correctly from what I can tell. Is there a firewall on Router1 (or 2) that might be blocking DNS port 53?

Comment: @gregg - Router2 is more sophisticated and has a lot of options and Router1 is provided by my ISP. So I try not to lose its capabilities by operating it in AP mode. Also, let me try the config to port forward 53 and see if that works.

Comment: Can you put Router1 in bridge mode? Disables all it's features except the modem/ISP functionality, even pass it's WAN IP to Router2. You'd have to plug all devices into Router2 then.

Comment: Cable from Router1 going to Router2, which port is it connected to on Router2, WAN/Internet?

Comment: @gregg - From Router1's LAN to Router2's internet. If I do port forwarding on Router2 for 192:168.1.12:53, I can access my DNS device on Router1 via 192.165.0.5:53. I believe my Router2 is blocking anything above it, not sure if there is a way to add an exception.

Comment: Try plugging into Router2's LAN port instead of internet. Port forwarding is a firewall exception, firewall is blocking everything else, Router2 thinks Router1 is the internet & protecting you from hackers

Answer (score 1):

Router2 must allow the inbound packets in the firewall settings. Most likely Router2 is in the typical configuration where it *thinks* that it's directly connected to the Internet, and uses a "safe" firewall configuration which blocks all new inbound connections from the "WAN" side.

(If Router2 has the NAT feature enabled, it *might* interfere with inbound connections, although it shouldn't. Still, with the static route in place, Router2 has no need to perform NAT and ideally should have it disabled.)

Also, your route destination doesn't quite match the specified netmask, as the netmask indicates that the entire 4th byte of the address is irrelevant, yet the destination has it specified. It *might* work anyway (the netmask will cause those bits to be ignored), but it also might be internally rejected by the router, depending on how picky the firmware is. (Some enforce 'canonical' notation, some don't.)

It should instead be either:

- destination `192.168.1.12` with netmask `255.255.255.255` (a single host), or
- destination `192.168.1.0` with netmask `255.255.255.0` (a /24 network).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried destination/netmask as per your comment but it didn't fix the problem. I will check if my Router2 is blocking all inbound connections and get back on this.